# Question of Triangle of Geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle ABC,we have $AB>AC$ . If A' is the mid point of BC,AD is the altitude through A and if the internal and external bisectors of angle A meet at BC at X and X' respectively ,prove that 
$A'D = (c^2-b^2)/2a$

I have tried to use obtuse angle theorem to find height then solve the question but stuck on double variable.

Sir here I tried to find height of triangle ABC but failed. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sir I have tried to use obtuse angle theorem to find height then solve the question but stuck on double variable

Comment: Just to clarify, $a, b, c$ refer to the length of the sides opposite to angles $A, B, C$ respectively?

Comment: Yes it refers to it

Comment: What's the purpose of having $X$ and $X'$? Also, how is it possible for both of them to be on $BC$? Can you add a drawing?

Comment: Here external angle bisector AX' meet BC on producing outside the triangle and internal bisector of A,AX meet BC inside the triangle

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Still, both points are not used so why even mention them?

Comment: Oh now you can help me in solving this!

Comment: Hey anyone not able to 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $c>b$, we obtain $\gamma>\beta,$ which says that $\angle ABC$ is an acute angle.

Thus, $$BD=c\cos\beta=\frac{c(a^2+c^2-b^2)}{2ac}=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}.$$
Also, me see that $BD>BA'$ because $c>b$.

Thus, $$A'D=BD-BA'=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{c^2-b^2}{2a}.$$